# ELASTIC_POOL not recognised by Visual Studio Database Project

Tags: sql-server, azure, t-sql, azure-sql-database, database-project

I am creating a Database project for a SQL Database in Azure.

The Target Platform is **Microsoft Azure SQL Database V12** which I have set in the project settings.

I then have a **post deployment script** containing the following code to add the database to an elastic pool

`ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)] MODIFY ( SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = ELASTIC_POOL ( name = mypoolname ) )`

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-azure-sql-database?view=azuresqldb-current#b-moving-a-database-to-a-different-elastic-pool

Because my Post Deployment script is set to build (because it has to as part of being a post deployment script) I get the following error:

> Error:  SQL72007: The syntax check failed 'Incorrect syntax near
>   ELASTIC_POOL.' in the batch near:

But I know the syntax is ok, it is obviously not recognising the Azure TSQL.

Is it possible to do this as part of my Visual Studio Database Project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're actually sending the query over to the database server, but in order to bypass a preliminary clientside syntax check you could simply use

```
exec sp_executesql N'ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)] MODIFY ( SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = ELASTIC_POOL ( name = mypoolname ) )'
```